# if statment with multiple column select

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know how to approach this problem, but I am trying to select information from multiple tables depending on where the data from the  `orders` table tells me to look, the first statment works but only returns information from table `orders_bought_a` and not from `orders_bought_b`

if an order comes from `location a` then I need to query to grab information from table `orders_bought_a`, the same should be done for `location b`.

Is there a way to do a block select in mysql such as the way I have done it in the preferred statement?

Any help would be appreciated, sorry if this looks like a mess, it was the best I could do.

**Current statement:**

```
SELECT oi.id         AS order_item_id,
       o.status,
       o.processed,
       oba.item_id   AS buy_item_id,
       oba.price     AS buy_price,
       oba.CONDITION AS buy_condition,
       obb.item_id   AS buy_item_id,
       obb.price     AS buy_price,
       obb.CONDITION AS buy_condition
FROM   order_items oi
       LEFT JOIN books b
              ON oi.isbn = b.isbn
       LEFT JOIN orders o
              ON o.id = oi.order_id
       LEFT JOIN orders_bought_a oba
              ON oba.id = oi.buy_order_id
       LEFT JOIN orders_bought_b obb
              ON obb.id = oi.buy_order_id
ORDER  BY date_ordered DESC
```

**Preferred (does not work):**

```
SELECT oi.id AS order_item_id, o.status, o.processed,  

    CASE
    WHEN(oi.location == 'a') THEN(
        oba.item_id AS buy_item_id, 
        oba.price AS buy_price, 
        oba.condition AS buy_condition
    )   

    WHEN(oi.location == 'b') THEN(      
        obb.item_id AS buy_item_id, 
        obb.price AS buy_price, 
        obb.condition AS buy_condition, 
    )       

FROM orders_items oi 
LEFT JOIN books b ON oi.isbn = b.isbn 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.id = oi.order_id 
LEFT JOIN orders_bought_a oba ON oba.id = oi.buy_order_id 
LEFT JOIN orders_bought_b obb ON obb.id = oi.buy_order_id 
ORDER BY date_ordered DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to select data from one table and union it with data from other table.
Something like this:

```
SELECT oi.id AS order_item_id, o.status, o.processed,
    oba.item_id AS buy_item_id, 
    oba.price AS buy_price, 
    oba.condition AS buy_condition

FROM orders_items oi 
LEFT JOIN books b ON oi.isbn = b.isbn 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.id = oi.order_id 
LEFT JOIN orders_bought_a oba ON oba.id = oi.buy_order_id 
WHERE oi.location = 'a'

UNION ALL

SELECT oi.id AS order_item_id, o.status, o.processed,
    obb.item_id AS buy_item_id, 
    obb.price AS buy_price, 
    obb.condition AS buy_condition,

FROM orders_items oi 
LEFT JOIN books b ON oi.isbn = b.isbn 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.id = oi.order_id 
LEFT JOIN orders_bought_b obb ON obb.id = oi.buy_order_id 
WHERE oi.location = 'b'
ORDER BY date_ordered DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, I should of thought about using a UNION before, I forget sometimes but you need to use one equal sign when making comparisons `oi.location = 'b'`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do what you want with `coalesce()` in the `select` statement and a slight modification to the `on` clauses for those joins:

```
SELECT oi.id AS order_item_id, o.status, o.processed,  
       coalesce(oba.item_id, obb.item_id) AS buy_item_id, 
       coalesce(oba.price, obb.price) AS buy_price, 
       coalesce(oba.condition, obb.condition) AS buy_condition
FROM order_items oi LEFT JOIN
     books b ON oi.isbn = b.isbn LEFT JOIN
     orders o ON o.id = oi.order_id LEFT JOIN
     orders_bought_a oba
     ON oba.id = oi.buy_order_id and
        oi.location = 'a' LEFT JOIN
     orders_bought_b obb
     ON obb.id = oi.buy_order_id and
        oi.location = 'b'
ORDER BY date_ordered DESC;
```